# How to compare 2 CSV files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 CSV files:

CSV 1 - original_names.csv

```
Serial,Names
1,James
2,Stephen
3,Ben
4,Harry
5,Jack
6, Peter
```

CSV 2 - dup_names.csv

```
Serial,Names
1,James
2,Kate
3,Ben
4,Sara
```

Desired Output - new.csv

```
Serial,Names,flag
1,0,T
2,Kate,F
3,0,T
4,Sara,F
5,Jack,F
6,Peter,F
```

As you can see, the same names in both CSV will be updated to 0 if names matches to new.csv.

This is what I've tried:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('original_names.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('dup_names.csv')

out = df1.merge(df2['names'], how='inner', on = 'names')

# some code

out.to_csv("new.csv", index=False)
```

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

Do an outer join, then just add some logic here. If the 2 name columns match, put a `'T'` flag in, else put `'F'`. Then replace the `'names'` should be `0` is `'T'`, else the name in the second csv. If there is no name in the second csv, fill those with the name from the first csv.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'serial':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
                     'names':['James','Stephen','Ben','Harry','Jack','Peter']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'serial':[1,2,3,4,],
                     'names':['James','Kate','Ben','Sara']})


out = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', on = ['serial'])

out['flag'] = np.where(out.names_x == out.names_y, 'T', 'F')
out['names'] = np.where(out.flag == 'T', 0, out.names_y)
out['names'] = out['names'].fillna(out.names_x)

out = out[['serial', 'names', 'flag']]
out.to_csv("new.csv", index=False)
```

**Output:**

```
print(out)
   serial  names flag
0       1      0    T
1       2   Kate    F
2       3      0    T
3       4   Sara    F
4       5   Jack    F
5       6  Peter    F
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.read_csv('original_names.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('dup_names.csv')

out = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on = 'Serial')

out['Names'] = np.where(out['Names_x'] == out['Names_y'], 
                        0, out['Names_y'])
out['Names'] = out['Names'].fillna(out['Names_x'])
out['flag'] = np.where(out['Names'] == 0, 'T', 'F')
out = out.drop(['Names_x', 'Names_y'], axis=1)

out.to_csv('new.csv', index=False)
```

**Output:**

```
   serial  names flag
0       1      0    T
1       2   Kate    F
2       3      0    T
3       4   Sara    F
4       5   Jack    F
5       6  Peter    F
```